# Self Hosting, Windows vs Console

Tags: owin, self-hosting

What are the advantages and disadvntages of Self Hosting Windows vs Web ? Which one should be preferred ?

We are developing an OWIN based Web App which will have some API's and few HTML files consuming those APIs and we are going for Self Hosting as we don't want to get tied up with IIS. I would like to know that where should I host my Web App, Windows or Console. And why ?

Answer (score 1):

The advantages and disadvantages would be:

**Self Hosting**

You can self host on a console, winforms, wcf or windows service app

Advantages

- Single package
- Simple instalation
- You don't depend on IIS

Disadvantages

- No fault tolerance
- Need aditional privileges to open http ports

**IIS Hosting**

Advantages

- Fault tolerance
- All the features of IIS that can be used on a web app

Disadvantages

- IIS dependency
- IIS administration privileges

As my experience I've used self hosting on a windows service for WCF services, and was a pretty good solution because it gave me the flexibility of a self host app with some fault tolerance of a windows service.

I would recommend IIS Hosting specially for big apps that drive a lot of traffic. Also in your case as you are serving html and web related files.